# Unable to reproduce CentOS 7.8 public IP routing network in Rocky 9.3

Tags: virtualization, linux-networking, rocky-linux

I have 2 servers. Both were set up the same and were working on Centos 7.8. I have re-imaged one machine using Rocky 9.3 and have been unsuccessful in getting the public IP routing to VMs to work.

The test for success is being able to ping the guest VM from the internet.
I can ping the public IP that I allocate brpub0.

I saved the configuration files from Rocky7 to put in Rocky9, and I can't find any difference using any configuration tools.
vagrant file and vms are run as non-privileged user `vmuser`.
I am aware that using the `ifcfg` files aren't really the way to do things on Rocky 9.3, but I 'm trying to rule out differences.
The Firewall is disabled on the non-working host
I have tried creating `brpub0` using `nmtui` - no joy

I am using Hetzner bare metal servers with additional public IP4 \28 addresses with vagrant and Virtualbox. Because of the way their networking works, the ip range won't get allocated MAC addresses, so we must use a router.
[Hetzner - additional IP addresses](https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/dedicated-server/ip/additional-ip-adresses/#subnets) , [Hetzner - network config for Centos - IP4 subnet for virtualisation](https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/dedicated-server/network/net-config-cent-os/#setting-up-an-additional-ipv4-subnet-for-virtualization)

### Works - VMHost

```
Main IP: aaa.bbb.217.101
Gateway: aaa.bbb.217.65
Netmask: 255.255.255.192
Broadcast: aaa.bbb.217.127

Public Range: mmm.nnn.207.144 / 28
Gateway: aaa.bbb.217.101
Netmask: 255.255.255.240
Broadcast: mmm.nnn.207.159
mmm.nnn.207.144 to mmm.nnn.207.159

ip route
default via aaa.bbb.217.65 dev enp0s31f6
mmm.nnn.207.144/28 dev brpub0 proto kernel scope link src mmm.nnn.207.145
aaa.bbb.217.65 dev enp0s31f6 proto kernel scope link src aaa.bbb.217.101
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s31f6 scope link metric 1002
169.254.0.0/16 dev brpub0 scope link metric 1003
192.168.35.0/24 dev vboxnet0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.35.1
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1

route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         aaa.bbb.217.65   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1
mmm.nnn.207.144    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 brpub0
aaa.bbb.217.65   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eno1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eno1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 brpub0
192.168.35.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
192.168.130.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet1



#/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s31f6
### Hetzner Online GmbH installimage

DEVICE=enp0s31f6
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=aaa.bbb.217.101
PREFIX=32
SCOPE="peer aaa.bbb.217.65"
DEFROUTE=yes

IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6ADDR=2a01:4f8:13b:1ad2::2/64
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=fe80::1
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_DEFAULTDEV=enp0s31f6


ifcfg-brpub0
# /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-brpub0 (pointopoint, Hetzner Standard)
DEVICE=brpub0
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=mmm.nnn.207.145
NETMASK=255.255.255.240
STP=off
DELAY=0


#/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-enp0s31f6
### Hetzner Online GmbH installimage

ADDRESS0=0.0.0.0
NETMASK0=0.0.0.0
GATEWAY0=aaa.bbb.217.65

Vagrant file
```

### Vagrant file - Works

```
$vmName = "WorkingVM"
$vmPrivateIp = "192.168.35.85"
$vmPublicIp = "mmm.nnn.207.150"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

config.vm.define $vmName do |vminstance|
vminstance.vm.box = "bento/centos-7.6"
vminstance.vm.network "private_network", ip: $vmPrivateIp, zone: "internal"
vminstance.vm.network "public_network",  ip: $vmPublicIp, bridge: "brpub0", \
          netmask: "255.255.255.240", gateway: $vmGatewayIp, dns1: "8.8.8.8", \
          zone: "public""
vminstance.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: $vmForwardPort

end # of vminstance
end # of config
```

### VM - works

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:c2:05:d3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic eth0
valid_lft 67512sec preferred_lft 67512sec
inet6 fe80::d1d5:4ed0:dcb7:badd/64 scope link noprefixroute
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:45:d2:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.35.84/24 brd 192.168.35.255 scope global noprefixroute eth1
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe45:d290/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:74:de:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet mmm.nnn.207.149/28 brd mmm.nnn.207.159 scope global noprefixroute eth2
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe74:debd/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         aaa.bbb.217.101  0.0.0.0         UG    102    0        0 eth2
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
mmm.nnn.207.144    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     102    0        0 eth2
aaa.bbb.217.101  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    102    0        0 eth2
192.168.35.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eth1
```

### VMHost - doesn't work

```
Main IP: aaa.bbb.129.56
Gateway: aaa.bbb.129.1
Netmask: 255.255.255.192
Broadcast: aaa.bbb.129.63

Public Range: xxx.yyy.89.0 / 28
Gateway: aaa.bbb.129.56
Netmask: 255.255.255.240
Broadcast: xxx.yyy.89.15
xxx.yyy.89.0 to xxx.yyy.89.15

vmhost-130
ip route
default via aaa.bbb.129.1 dev eno1 proto static metric 100
xxx.yyy.89.0/28 dev brpub0 proto kernel scope link src xxx.yyy.89.1 metric 425 linkdown
aaa.bbb.129.1 dev eno1 proto static scope link metric 100
192.168.56.0/24 dev vboxnet0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.56.1 

route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         aaa.bbb.129.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno1
xxx.yyy.89.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     425    0        0 brpub0
aaa.bbb.129.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eno1
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet0

# /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1
### Hetzner Online GmbH installimage   
DEVICE=eno1
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=aaa.bbb.129.56
PREFIX=32
GATEWAY=aaa.bbb.129.1
DEFROUTE=yes
DNS1=185.12.64.1
DNS2=2a01:4ff:ff00::add:2    
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6ADDR=2a01:4f8:13b:3ac7::2/64
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=fe80::1
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes

# /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-brpub0 (pointopoint, Hetzner Standard)
DEVICE=brpub0
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=xxx.yyy.89.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.240
STP=off
DELAY=0


# /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-en01
### Hetzner Online GmbH installimage   
ADDRESS0=0.0.0.0
NETMASK0=0.0.0.0
GATEWAY0=aaa.bbb.129.1
```

### Vagrant file - doesn't work

```
$vmName = "NotWorking"
$vmBox = "generic/rocky9"
$vmPublicIp = "xxx.yyy.89.12"
$vmGatewayIp = "aaa.bbb.129.56"
$vmPrivateIp = "192.168.56.10"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

config.vm.define $vmName do |vminstance|
vminstance.vm.box = $vmBox
vminstance.vm.network "private_network", ip: $vmPrivateIp, zone: "internal"
vminstance.vm.network "public_network",  ip: $vmPublicIp, bridge: "brpub0", \
         netmask: ""255.255.255.240"", gateway: $vmGatewayIp, dns1: "8.8.8.8", \ 
         zone: "public""
vminstance.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: $vmForwardPort

end
end
```

### VM - doesn't work

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:cb:b3:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
altname enp0s3
inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
valid_lft 85553sec preferred_lft 85553sec
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:01:17:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
altname enp0s8
inet 192.168.56.10/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global noprefixroute eth1
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe01:1749/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:80:d4:52 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
altname enp0s9
inet xxx.yyy.89.12/28 brd xxx.yyy.89.15 scope global noprefixroute eth2
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe80:d452/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         aaa.bbb.129.56   0.0.0.0         UG    102    0        0 eth2
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
xxx.yyy.89.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     102    0        0 eth2
aaa.bbb.129.56   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    102    0        0 eth2
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eth1
```