# bridge for virtualisation stays in state DOWN - unable to get it up

Tags: networking, virtualization, bridge, networkmanager, rocky-linux

Running Rocky 9.3, attempting to get a bridge for a public Range of IPs for use with Virtual machines.

Same hardware used to run Centos 7.8 machine with it all working, am now trying to set it up the same with Rocky 9.3

```
# /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-brpub0 (pointopoint, Hetzner Standard)
DEVICE=brpub0
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=xxx.yyy.89.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.240
STP=off
DELAY=0
```

gives

```
3: br0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6a:1f:e1:44:ec:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xxx.yyy.89.1/28 brd xxx.yyy.89.15 scope global noprefixroute br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I installed vagrant and Virtualbox same as before and although I can ping the bridge on `xxx.yyy.89.1` I can't ping the public IP address allocated to the vm.

For reference, on another machine that is still on centos 7, the equivalent is

```
3: brpub0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5e:ce:35:cf:d2:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet aa.bb.207.145/28 brd aa.bb.207.159 scope global brpub0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5**e:35**:f**f:d290/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Why is my bridge down? whatever I do in terms of `nmcli` and link/device commands, it stays down. How do I get it up?

--- Edit ---

As requested by @larsks, `ip link show master brpub0` on the working machine  - has no output

```
[root@prod-vmhost-114 ~]# ip link show master brpub0
[root@prod-vmhost-114 ~]#
```

[Very detailed description here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1153015/unable-to-reproduce-centos-7-8-public-ip-routing-network-in-rocky-9-3)

Comment: I don't think this is actually a problem. On my Fedora 39 system, the `virbr0` bridge to which most of my virtual machines are attached shows `NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP`, and I am able to communicate with the vms without a problem.

Comment: thanks @larsks - helpful, but not the answer I was after ;-) This is the only difference I can see in the network setup between the old and new operating system. 
I can't even ping the VM from the host machine using that address range. I'm fine with a local network, just not this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened between CentOS 7 and Rocky Linux 9? A newer *systemd* version.

With older *systemd*, *systemd* didn't peek on bridges, they were left alone when created. With newer versions of *systemd*, *systemd* monitors virtual interface creations and will assign a "stable random" MAC address on it instead of leaving the (fully) random MAC address set by default, as soon as its creation is detected. This has a side effect of immediately setting the bridge's operational state (aka *operstate*) to `DOWN`, because this has changed its default mode of operation and it has no bridge port (yet).

So if you create twice a bridge on CentOS 7, you can expect its MAC address to change, similar to this:

```shell
# ip link add name testbr0 up type bridge
# ip link show dev testbr0
3: testbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether de:6b:22:95:cf:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
# ip link del dev testbr0
# ip link add name testbr0 up type bridge
# ip link show testbr0
4: testbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:75:85:6b:a8:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

In this example: first time de:6b:22:95:cf:76 second time 02:75:85:6b:a8:d4

Note how the examples above show the bridge *operstate* is `UNKNOWN`.

Now if a MAC address is set on the bridge:

```shell
# ip link set dev testbr0 address b6:00:00:00:00:01
# ip link show dev testbr0
3: testbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b6:00:00:00:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

This changes the mode of the bridge from "no MAC address assigned" to "been assigned a MAC address".

Notice how the bridge *operstate* when from `UNKNOWN` to `DOWN`.

Now in any Linux system running a newer *systemd*, including Rocky Linux 9, this assignation is systematically done (this could be verified by leaving a `ip monitor link` running).

```shell
# ip link add name testbr0 up type bridge
# ip link show dev testbr0
21: testbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 92:45:24:9e:58:8e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
# ip link del dev testbr0
# ip link add name testbr0 up type bridge
# ip link show testbr0
22: testbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 92:45:24:9e:58:8e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Notice how the supposed-to-be-random MAC address is twice the same: *systemd*, whatever the Network Manager in use, assigned twice the same MAC address on it as soon as it detected it was created without assigning an address.

As above this makes the *operstate* `DOWN` instead of `UNKNOWN`. While the *operstate* was `UNKNOWN`, it was temporarily considered as `UP`, until the first bridge port is assigned to it. Then the behavior would become the same.

As the bridge is *operstate* `DOWN`, it won't setup a link-local IPv6 address, as seen in this Q/A: [linux ipv6 bridge address does not work when mac address is forced](https://serverfault.com/questions/1062421/linux-ipv6-bridge-address-does-not-work-when-mac-address-is-forced) and as seen in OP's examples.

For IPv6 there will be issues, for IPv4 I'm not sure there are visible issues, unless an interface flag such as [`ignore_routes_with_linkdown`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v6.6#n1878) is enabled on this interface.

If wanting the bridge to be always in *operstate* `UP`, to get a consistent behavior, add a bridge port that is `UP`. If you don't want to use any, still add a dummy one. Continuing the example above:

```shell
# ip link add name testbr0p0 up master testbr0 type dummy
# ip link show testbr0
22: testbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 92:45:24:9e:58:8e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

The bridge interface's *operstate* is now UP.

---

More information about *systemd*'s change of behavior and the change of the behavior of the bridge when explicitly assigned or not assigned a MAC address can be seen in these UL SE, SF and SU Q/A where I made an answer:

- [How can I make Linux generate different MAC addresses for different bridge devices which are on different PCs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/719379/how-can-i-make-linux-generate-different-mac-addresses-for-different-bridge-devic/719391#719391)
- [Debian: Where does a bridge interface store its MAC address and how can I change it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1127889/debian-where-does-a-bridge-interface-store-its-mac-address-and-how-can-i-change)
- [How does Linux determine the default MAC address of a bridge device?](https://superuser.com/questions/1720967/how-does-linux-determine-the-default-mac-address-of-a-bridge-device)

Comment: This answers my question, so marked as answer. Doesn't fix my problem which turns out to be not due to this - can't route these public IP addresses to my VM

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1153112/centos-7-where-else-to-look-for-a-difference-in-network-setup

Comment: I saw it too, but I can only answer questions I know an answer for... For questions with a whole setup,  I usually attempt to reproduce them with a mock-up. Can't do this with the little provided in that other question. (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example except it's setup rather  than code. *minimal* is important, else a mock-up is too difficult). Note that there's a recent answer that does answer your question. Can't tell if it will answer the actual not-so-visible problem.

Answer (score 0):

I realized after leaving my comment that you were working with VirtualBox, whereas I am using [libvirt](https://libvirt.org/). These two tools handle network bridging in fundamentally different ways.

### Libvirt and Linux bridge devices

Libvirt operates using Linux bridge device. When you create a "network", libvirt creates a Linux bridge device. Out of the box, you would typically have a network named "default" associated with a bridge device named `virbr0`. With no interfaces attached to the bridge, it looks like this:

```
$ ip link show virbr0
6: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e6:ff:5f:32:ed:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

After we start a virtual machine, we see a new interface attached to the bridge:

```
$ ip link show master virbr0
7: veth0@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master virbr0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2e:b6:db:05:a0:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

And the bridge interface is now fully up:

```
$ ip link show virbr0
6: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e6:ff:5f:32:ed:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

### VirtualBox and bridged adapters

All of the above is completely academic, because a VirtualBox "bridged adapter" has **nothing to do with Linux bridge devices**. When you connect a VirtualBox interface to a "bridged adapter", VirtualBox creates its own analog of a bridge device to attach the virtual interface to the selected hosted interface.

In other words, if you have an interface `eth2` on a public network and you want to connect a VirtualBox machine to that network, you **do not** create a Linux bridge device, add `eth2` to the bridge, and then connect your virtual machine to the bridge.

Instead, you select `eth2` as the target of your bridged adapter in VirtualBox.

The equivalent Vagrant configuration would look something like this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "generic/rocky9"
  config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "eth2"
end
```

If we watch the kernel logs while running `vagrant up`, we'll see something like:

```
Feb 07 09:36:28 fizzgig kernel: vboxdrv: 00000000a064d924 VBoxDDR0.r0
Feb 07 09:36:28 fizzgig kernel: VBoxNetFlt: attached to 'eth2' / 60:7d:09:44:3e:a9
Feb 07 09:36:28 fizzgig kernel: r8152 2-1:1.0 eth2: entered promiscuous mode
Feb 07 09:36:28 fizzgig kernel: r8152 2-1:1.0 eth2: Promiscuous mode enabled
```

And at this point, the virtual machine should have access to the public network.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The irony is that one of the reasons for the change is to change over to KVM instead of Virtualbox, couldn't get it to work, so went back to try and recreate it as a working system.

The thing that's driving me mad is the fact that it *was* working and still is working on another machine.  

I've created 
https://serverfault.com/questions/1153112/centos-7-where-else-to-look-for-a-difference-in-network-setup
To try and see what the difference is.

Comment: The fact that on your centos 7 system the bridge is fully up suggests that there are devices attached to it. What is the output of `ip link show master brpub0` on the centos 7 system? Probably best to just put the information in your question, since it won't format well in a comment.