# Centos 7 - where else to look for a difference in network setup

Tags: centos, virtualization, linux-networking, virtualbox

I have 2 Hetzner dedicated machines with public ip4/28 address ranges.
Both were working with Centos 7.8, vagrant and Virtualbox - I could create vms with public IP addresses.
I wiped one and set it up using Rocky 9.3 but couldn't get the networking to work.
I have re-imaged it back to Centos 7.9 with the same original versions of vagrant and Virtualbox, but still no joy.
I can ping the bridge's IP address, so it's being routed to the machine OK, but can't seem to route to the vm.

I have compared the following and can't see any difference in the host machine setup.

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eno1
ip address
ip route
route -n
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
ip route show match for ****** IP address
```

I'm copying the Vagrantfile from one machine to the other, so the only difference is the public ip address.

Where else can I check to find the difference between the working and non-working machines?

Answer (score 0):

1. ip link show
2. ifconfig
3. ip addr show
4. cat /etc/resolv.conf
5. ethtool eth0
6. cat /etc/hosts
7. tracepath 8.8.8.8
8. iptables -L